# В phpmyadmin заблокировал сам себя

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

Столкнулся с проблемой, что в phpmyadmin заблокировал доступ root-пользователю. При попытке входа появляется такое сообщение:
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/4151): Access denied, this account is locked
Как я могу разрешить доступ root пользователю, если в консоли мне даже не дают выполнить команду mysql?

Comment: осталось сделать ровно противоположное тому, что вы уже успешно проделали: «заблокировал доступ».

Comment: Если не существует активного пользователя с правом разблокирования пользователей - то читаем https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html и выполняем Generic Instructions, только вместо смены пароля разлочиваем рута.